# Inline функции в C и С++

Tags: c++, c

В чем разница `inline` функций в C и C++? Желательно со ссылкой на стандарт.

Comment: Ну например в стандартном C inline функции появились только в 99 стандарте (хотя как расширения поддерживались многими компиляторами и до этого).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как в С так и в С++ ключевое слово `inline` не гарантирует встраивания функции в вызывающий код, а является лишь пожеланием компилятору, что данная функция должна вызываться настолько быстро, насколько возможно. Поэтому осязаемым эффектом ключевого слова `inline` является только то, как оно влияет на правила объявления и определения функций.

Если рассматривать функции с внутренним связыванием, т.е. функции, объявленные как `static inline`, то разницы между C и С++ фактически нет (если я ничего не упускаю).

Однако как только речь заходит о функциях с внешним связыванием, то разница между языками довольна значительна.

- В С++ правила просты: допускаются множественные определения `inline` функций (в разных единицах трансляции). При этом если функция объявлена `inline` в одной единице трансляции, то и во всех остальных единицах трансляции, где она объявлена, она должна быть объявлена именно `inline`. Во всех единицах трансляции, где эта функция определена, она должна быть определена одинаково.
- В языке С же проводится довольно запутанное деление между inline-определениями функции и external-определениями функции.

  - Inline-определение возникает тогда, когда в данной единице трансляции все объявления данной функции сделаны с ключевым словом `inline`, но ни одно не содержит ключевого слова `extern`. В такой ситуации определение функции не создает внешнего символа - к нему нельзя прилинковаться из другого объектного файла.

    В inline-определениях запрещается определять модифицируемые статические объекты и thread-локальные объекты. Также оттуда нельзя ссылаться на сущности (объекты и функции) с внутренним связыванием.
  - External-определение возникает тогда, когда в данной единице трансляции либо есть  "обычное" объявление функции (без `inline`), либо объявление сразу с двумя ключевыми словами `extern inline`. External-определение является обычной функцией - оно порождает внешний символ к которому можно прилинковаться из другого объектного файла - достаточно сделать там *объявление* этой функции.

  Например

  ```
  inline void foo(); // Объявление
  inline void bar(); // Объявление

  inline void foo()  // Определение
  {
    static int i = 42;
  }

  inline void bar()  // Определение
  {
    static int j = 42; // Ошибка!
  }

  void foo();        // Объявление
  inline void bar(); // Объявление
  ```

  В данном примере определение функции `bar` является ошибочным, т.к. это inline-определение, а в inline-определениях нельзя определять модифицируемые статические объекты.

  В то же время определение функции `foo` является external-определением потому, что ниже по тексту встречается объявление это функции без слова `inline`. На такое определение никаких ограничений не накладывается.

  Далее

  - Если в какой-то единице трансляции наличествует inline-определение функции, и нигде в проекте нет extern-определения этой функции - то вызываться будет именно inline-определение.
  - Если в какой-то единице трансляции наличествует inline-определение функции, и где-то в проекте есть extern-определение этой функции - то компилятор имеет право сам выбрать, какое определение вызывать.